# Angular2 Http Override inject Router

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-routing

In our Angular2 RC4 application with the old component router, we have overridden the default Http Class to catch http 401 Unauthenticated requests and redirect them to the login page.
This redirect happens with the Angular router.

We want to update to version 2.0.1 now and use the new router. To do this, we must also inject the new router into the custom Http override class.
Compilation succeeds, but Angular won't run, because when the app starts, it tries to create the custom http class before the first component is loaded. It is no longer possible to inject the new router before loading the first component.

What is the best way to proceed here?
Should we manually inject the Router after instantiating the Http override class?
How can that be done?

Below is our code of the custom Http class that works in RC4 with the old router.
When updating to the final version, the problem is in catchUnauthorized, because the router can not be injected into this class anymore.

```
﻿import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers, ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Request} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Router} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private router: Router) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
}

postJson(url: string, object: any, options: RequestOptionsArgs = {}): Observable<Response> {
    var body = JSON.stringify(object);

    if(!options.headers)
    {
        options.headers = new Headers();
    }

    options.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this.post(url, body, options);
}

request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.request(url, options)
        .catch(this.catchUnauthorized);
}

get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.get(url, options)
        .catch(this.catchUnauthorized);
}

post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.post(url, body, options)
        .catch(this.catchUnauthorized);
}

put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.put(url, body, options)
        .catch(this.catchUnauthorized);
}

delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.delete(url, options)
        .catch(this.catchUnauthorized);
}

patch(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.patch(url, body, options)
        .catch(this.catchUnauthorized);
}

head(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return super.head(url, options)
        .catch(this.catchUnauthorized);
}

public catchUnauthorized = (error: Response) => {
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 440) {
        var currentInstruction = this.router.currentInstruction;
        var instruction = this.router.generate(["/Login", { "session": "true", "returnUrl": currentInstruction.toLinkUrl() }]);

        if (currentInstruction.urlPath != instruction.urlPath)
            this.router.navigateByInstruction(instruction);

        return Observable.throw('Sessie verlopen!');
    }
    if (error.status === 403) {
        this.router.navigate(['/Error', { 'error': 'forbidden' }]);
        return Observable.throw('Forbidden!');
    }
    return Observable.throw(error);
};
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the router from `@angular/router-deprecated`. You should be using the one from `@angular/router`

Comment: As I said in the question, this is the way it was in our RC4 version.
To migrate to the final version, the old @angular/router-deprecated is removed everywhere and the new @angular/router is used.
But I can't figure out how to migrate this class over to the new router, because this class has to be provided throughout the entire app and it needs a router. But the new router can't be injected before any component is loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try to add "Router" to "deps":

```
...
providers: [
{
  provide: CustomHttp,
  useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions, route: Router) => {
    return new CustomHttp(backend, options, route);
  },
  deps: [ XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router ]
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom class, but everywhhere have imports from '@angular/http', provider must provide Http class from '@angular/http',

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {CustomHttp} from 'my/custom/location';

function httpFactory(backend, options){
   return new CustomHttp(backend, options);
}

{
   provide: Http,
   useFactory: httpFactory,
   deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
}
```

You can even put httpFactory method to same file, as CustomHttp class